# Assigning local variable from global variable node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following two files

`global.js`

```
// global.js

a_var = {a: 1};
require('./local.js');
```

`local.js`

```
// local.js

var b_var = (a_var || {});
console.log(b_var);
```

Running `node global.js`, this prints as expected

> { a: 1 }

Now consider these two files

`global.js`

```
//global.js

a_var = {a: 1};
require('./local.js');
```

`local.js`

```
var a_var = (a_var || {});
console.log(a_var);
```

This prints

> {}

What's going on here?
Node version - `v6.3.0`

Comment: You're re-declaring `a_var` inside `local.js`, how can that get the value from `global.js`?

Comment: @ChatterOne shouldn't the right side of the assignment be evaluated first?

Comment: @aandis — No, it really shouldn't. Please read up on hoisting, it is a fundamental part of JS.

Comment: You're probably missing the concept of "hoisting". There are articles that explain it in the detail, but the basic idea is that you can use a variable before you declare it because the declarations are moved to the top of the current scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding outer scope's variable `'a_var'` with inner scope's variable `'a_var'`, which is undefined while evaluating `(a_var || {})`.

read [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript) to expand your knowledge with javascript scopes.